# Database.EnsureCreated does not seem that it's creating a database (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple app using **EntityFramework** and **Sqlite** as database to add and save the person into the data base and add it to a ListView, or delete it.

I have a Db class, and in the constructor method i used the method called

`Database.EnsureCreated()`

to make my database. And in the MainPage.xaml.cs i made an instance of the Db class(db) and i wanted to get all the Workers table in my database and pass it as the ItemSource of a ListView. Also i'm doing these in `OnAppearing()` method to show my ListView items on the startup, but i face this exception error:

> **Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteExceptions: 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such table:Workers'.'**

(see the image below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1plJm.png)

That it seems the `Database.EnsureCreated()` is not creating my database.
or maybe it creates my database but it can't create the tables for some reasons and i want to know those reasons

And here's my Db class:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7PJd.png)

And this is my db_path:
**Android**:

```
        string FileName = "Workers.sqlite";
    string FileLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string db_path = Path.Combine(FileLocation, FileName);
```

And the **iOS**:

```
            string FileName = "Workers.sqlite";
        string FileLocation = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..", "Library");
        string db_path = Path.Combine(FileLocation, FileName);
```

**So what is the problem with the database and table creation?**

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `using` keyword to those lines and it fixed it unexpectedly.

(I also removed some of those db_path variables and made the db_path source cleaner and more fluent by getting it from the App class).

Now the code looks like this:

```
        using (Db db = new Db(App.db_path))
        {
            List<Worker> AllWorkers = db.Workers.ToList();
            WorkersListView.ItemsSource = AllWorkers;
        }
```